# Div doesn't fills the 50% of the container

Tags: jquery, css

I need to fill one div with another two divs and these divs has to fill the 50% of the parent div, but the child divs only fills its content.

```css
.uno {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}

.dos {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}

.super {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="super">
  <div class="uno">
    aaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="dos">
    bbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing `display` to `block` and add `float: left`.

Comment: Change `block` to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: General rule of thumb: you can't give widths to inline elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `float:left` properties. Please check this:

```css
.uno{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
.dos{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
.super{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="super">
      <div class="uno">
        aaaaaa
      </div>
      <div class="dos">
        bbbbb
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: put float:left and display:block as shown below

```css
.uno{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  display:block;
}
.dos{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  display:block;

}
.super{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="super">
      <div class="uno">
        aaaaaa
      </div>
      <div class="dos">
        bbbbb
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier - try to change 'display' of children elements to 'block' and add 'float': 'left' in css. 
But you will have the problem - parent will behave like it has no children. Simplest way to fix it - add 'overflow': 'hidden' to .super

Answer (score 0):

@AFS, if you use float, you lose parent's height.
Solution with flex.

```css
.uno{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
}
.dos{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}
.super{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
    <div class="super">
      <div class="uno">
        aaaaaa
      </div>
      <div class="dos">
        bbbbb
      </div>
    </div>
```